# How to use <a> Tag to show children View on top of parent in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I have been trying to display partial children view on top of parent view using hyperlink. But nothing happens when I click on my hyperlink. on the other hand it is working on normal button.

**Here is the code that works without any problem on normal button.**

```
  <button type="button" id="close_register" title="{{ __('cash_register.close_register') }}" class='button-custom' data-container=".close_register_modal" 
      data-href="{{ action('CashRegisterController@getCloseRegister')}}">
        <!-- <strong><i class="fa fa-window-close fa-lg"></i></strong> -->
  </button>
```

**And here is the hyperlink based button code.**

```
<a id="close_register" data-container=".close_register_modal" 
data-href="{{ action('CashRegisterController@getCloseRegister')}}" class='glowBtn'>Day Close
</a>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is not a Laravel problem, but a simple HTML one. Your  tag is missing an HREF attribute. Use `javascript:void(0);`, if you want to avoid reloading the page unexpectedly.

```
<a
    id="close_register"
    data-container=".close_register_modal" 
    data-href="{{ action('CashRegisterController@getCloseRegister')}}"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    class='glowBtn'>Day Close
</a>
```